# Get (console?)logs from iPhone Settings app

Tags: ios, ios8

I've never used, let alone debugged, an iPhone until today - please be gentle.

I'm trying to install onto an iOS 8 iPhone a VPN configuration .mobileconfig file of my own creation, and it is failing.  I was fully expecting not to get it right first time - now I need to debug it.

How can I get logs of the failure please?

I have not been able to find a working app in the App Store.  "LogPolice", for example, just shows an empty log.

XCode on a Mac refuses to connect to the process.  I select Debug -> Attach to Process -> Settings (xx) and it tells me

> Lost connection to "iPhone".
>   Restore the connection to "iPhone" and run
>   "Settings" again, of if "Settings" is still running, you 
>   can attach to it by selecting Debug > Attach to
>   Process > Settings

Retrying, restarting XCode, restarting the mac, restarting the phone have no effect.

I have at my disposal a Mac, a Windows PC (for which I do not have admin rights) and a Ubuntu VM (for which I have admin rights).  Happy to use any of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't debug the settings app as it's not an app you'll have the debug symbols for.

You can view the devices console which should shed some more light on the issue. See this reddit comment to locate it in Xcode: https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/294kj4/where_did_the_console_from_devices_go_in_xcode_6/cihel8l

Comment: Short answer in case that link disappears: to view the console, XCode -> Window -> Devices ->  select device and click the ^ icon in the bottom-left of the right-hand pane.